# Erro Electron utilizando "escpos" e "electron-rebuild": não é um aplicativo Win32 válido

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, windows, electron

estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação desktop com electron e estou com o seguinte problema ao tentar rodar a aplicação no Windows:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tudo isso começou após eu instalar o framework "escpos" para trabalhar com impressora térmica e "electron-rebuild" pois precisei roda um rebuild para fazer o framework funcionar.

Estou desenvolvendo e compilando, para Windows, em uma máquina Linux (Debian) utilizando o electron-packager.

Segue meu package.json, caso possa ajudar:

```
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "elect.js",
  "build": {
    "appId": "br.com.app"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64  --icon=src/assets/icons/icon-1024.png --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-windows-32": "electron-packager . app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=src/assets/icons/windows/logo-32x32.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^4.1.1",
    "escpos": "^2.4.11",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "internet-available": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "serialport": "^7.1.4",
    "serve-static": "^1.13.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.6.0",
    "electron-packager": "^13.1.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Depois de algum tempo lidando, resolvi a questão utilizando uma máquina virtual windows para compilar o aplicativo. Porém, lá também tive alguns problemas e segui os seguintes passos para resolve-lo:

1. Instalei o node-gyp globalmente
2. Instalei a versão 2.7 do Python
3. Configurei o Python com o seguinte comando: `npm config set python "c:\Python27\python.exe"`
4. Com um prompt em modo administrador rodei os seguintes comandos:
   `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
   npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global`
5. Rodei um rebuild: `.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd`
6. Por fim rodei um `npm install`